# In Mongoose, Duplicate key error collection with save method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my project, I'd like to make a simple user management program with MongoDB.

So I built a local server using Express of NodeJS and connected it to MongoDB.

After that, a schema called User was declared in Mongoose, and I made and tested a rest api that simply inserts data.

However, as a second attempt, duplicate key error collection occurred when testing with different uid values. (A first attempt was successful)

Can you tell me what's wrong with my design?

```
// models/user.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uid: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
    },
    birth: {
        type: Date,
    },
    delivery_password: {
        type: String,
    }
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

// Create Model & Export
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```
// routers/users.js (only routing code)
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  const user = new User({
    uid: 'lhj23',
    password: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test@google.gmail',
    phone: '01000000000',
    birth: new Date('2000-01-01'),
    delivery_password: '1234',
  });

  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.json({
        result: 0,
        message: err.message
      });
      return;
    }

    res.json({ result: 1 });
  });
})
```

```
// error message
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.users index: id_1 dup key: { id: null }
    at Function.create (C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:57:12)
    at toError (C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:130:22)
    at C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:258:39
    at handler (C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:943:24)
    at C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:350:13
    at handleOperationResult (C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:281:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at processIncomingData (C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\test\android\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:745:22)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9) {
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { id: 1 },
  keyValue: { id: null }
}
```

---

Edit 1
Calling that rest api, I created user instance like this.

```
const user = new User({
    uid: 'lhj',
    password: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test@naver.com',
    phone: '01000000000',
    birth: new Date('2000-01-01'),
    delivery_password: '1234',
  });
```

And, this was a second one.

```
const user = new User({
    uid: 'lhj23',
    password: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test@naver.com',
    phone: '01000000000',
    birth: new Date('2000-01-01'),
    delivery_password: '1234',
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ***userSchema*** you have defined ***uid*** as unique and when you are calling your ***/test*** endpoint you are always passing the same ***uid*** which is not unique, instead of that use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4) for the ***uid*** field.

```
const { uuid } = require('uuidv4');
router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  const user = new User({
   uid: uuid(),
   password: 'test',
   name: 'test',
   email: 'test@google.gmail',
   phone: '01000000000',
   birth: new Date('2000-01-01'),
   delivery_password: '1234',
});
.....
//save here
}
```

Comment: Oh, there is a missing point in my question. Could you check my question agagin??

Comment: Please post your complete schema, because from logs it seems that you have one more key which is **id** and you are facing an issue with that key only and you are passing null to that key everytime

Comment: Thats my word! Unfortunately, this is my complete schema.... **id** was never written by my hand....

Comment: Oh, I found the answer! I perfectly removed my local mongodb and installed again. And, I used Model.create method instead of save. Like this
`await User.create({
      service_id: req.body.service_id,
      password: req.body.password,
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      birth: req.body.birth,
      delivery_password: req.body.delivery_password,
    });`
Then it worked!!

Comment: I tried the snippet shared by you in the question and it was giving the expected output. Maybe you missed something as your error logs clearly point that you were passing null in the **id** field

Comment: Yap, I think so... Thank you for you help!

Comment: Anyway you can mark the answer as accepted